# Fly on a jet pack vs fly with a jet pack?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, idiomatic-language

Neither "fly on a jet pack" nor "fly with a jet pack" sounds idiomatic, are they? And are there better alternatives, because I can't really think of other ways of saying it.

For example:

> I fly on a jet pack above the lake to attract tourists.
>
> I fly with a jet pack above the lake to attract tourists.

Comment: **Strapped to a jet pack...** or **Powered by a jet pack**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correcting your sentence: Neither "fly on a jet pack" nor "fly with a jet pack" sounds idiomatic, **do** they?

Ronald Sole gave you two very good alternatives.

Flying "on a jet pack" makes it sound as if you are sitting or lying down on something. Most jet packs I've ever seen (very few) are strapped around the person. Now if we were talking about a flying carpet, "on" would be fine.  Of course, if they invent a jet pack that one lies or sits on while flying, your sentence would be fine.

Your second example, "I fly with a jet pack above the lake to attract tourists," is acceptable.  The word "with" can be used to show instrumentality. In other words, you are using something as a tool.  For example, I am driving nails into the wood with a hammer.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up many examples of "fly with a jetpack", from various sources. It may not sound idiomatic to *you*, but that doesn't mean it's not perfectly normal to others.

Comment: Actually, I wrote, "Your second example," 'I fly with a jet pack above the lake to attract tourists,' is acceptable.  I meant to show approval.  I didn't say that it was not idiomatic.

Comment: Ok, but it sounds like you qualify it by saying it can only be used when describing it as a tool for some other purpose.  If you check my examples below, all relate to flying in and of itself.

Comment: +1 for also correcting "are they" at the end of OP's first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"Fly with a jetpack" is fine:

> [Martin Aircraft is making it possible for the masses to **fly with a jetpack**](https://blogs.solidworks.com/solidworksblog/2012/05/flying-high-with-martin-aircraft.html)
>
> [Watch the second episode of Bridget's Adventures to see what it is like to **"fly" with a jetpack.**](https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/flying-over-water-with-a-jetpack)
>
> [Sims can **fly with a jetpack** even when they do not have any Advanced Technology skill.](https://sims.fandom.com/wiki/Jetpack)

as well as many others.  It sounds fine to me.

You would not say "on" a jetpack because you are *wearing* it, not *riding* it.  Harry Potter, for example. flies *on* a broomstick, because he rides it -- but he might fly *with* a pair of magical winged boots, because he wears them.

Note that "jetpack" is frequently spelled as one word.